# Django join models based on unique key

Tags: django, join

I have a situation where I can't join models based on foreign key. I want to join them based on common key that is basically foreign key to third table.

Have a look at code:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

class Chat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    thread =  models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField(default= 0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

class User_Thread(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reciever', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to join Chat and User_Thread models based on same thread. How can I achieve this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `User_Thread`s of a given `Chat` with:

```
my_chat.thread.user_thread_set.all()
```

If you want to do this for a number of `Chat`s, you can [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) these with:

```
chats = Chat.objects.select_related('thread').prefetch_related('thread__user_thread')
```

This will perform two queries, and do the JOIN at the Django/Python layer. Doing such JOIN in a query would result in a huge number of records that likely contain  a lot of duplicate data, hence you can not use [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for that.

You can then thus iterate over the chats, and for example list the `User_Thread`s with:

```
for chat in chats:
    for ut in chat.thread.user_thread_set.all():
        print(''.format(chat.message, ut.receiver_id))
```